# Access-Query for data on listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, listbox

I need to update a listbox in Access displaying data filtered by input from a combobox. The combobox has three columns:

ID Tipo di prodotto
Tipo di Prodotto
ID Categoria

The first one is the one I need for the filter, the second one is just the text displayed, the third one I'll use it later on.

My code is the following:

```
Private Sub Prodtypelistcb_AfterUpdate()
Dim myquery As String
myquery = "SELECT Prodotto.[ID Prodotto], Prodotto.[Nome prodotto],Prodotto.[ID Tipodiprodotto]" & _
"FROM Prodotto WHERE (Prodotto.[ID Tipodiprodotto]=Maschere!Brand!Prodtypelistcb.Value)"

Me.Brandprodel.Visible = True
Me.Brandprodel.RowSource = myquery
Me.Brandprodel.Requery

End Sub
```

prodtypelistcb is the combobox to be updated as input action and Brandprodel is the listbox to be updated after the action. If i put WHERE=1 everything works so the code should be ok excluding the query.

Nothing happens with this one. Where am I wrong?

UPDATE

If I set the value on the combobox and go for a pure query using access interface, it displays what I need. So the problem could be in retrieving the combobox value after I update it, but cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in the SQL.

```
Dim myquery As String
    myquery = "SELECT [ID Prodotto], [Nome prodotto], [ID Tipodiprodotto] " & _ 
              "FROM Prodotto WHERE [ID Tipodiprodotto] = " & _ 
              Me!Prodtypelistcb.Column(1)
```

Comment: It works thanks. Anyway I don't undestand why the query I used before worked if used into access query generator and did not work if written in VBA.

Comment: An Access query knows `Maschere!Brand!Prodtypelistcb.Value` is a control but VBA thinks it's only a String value since it's wrapped in `"` quotes.